# Ionic QR Scanner returns previous value

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins

I have a problem with QR Scanner Ionic Plugin ( I tried a lot of versions )
The problem is that the scanner returns the value of the previous scan, and of course the first scan is empty.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { QRScanner, QRScannerStatus } from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor() {
    this.ionApp.style.display = 'block';
  }
  public error="Sample";
  public counter = 0;
  public ionApp = <HTMLElement>document.getElementsByTagName('ion-app')[0];
  public data= "";
  public startScanner(){
    QRScanner.prepare()
    .then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
       if (status.authorized) {
         this.ionApp.style.display = ' none';
         // camera permission was granted
          QRScanner.show();

         // start scanning
         let scanSub = QRScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => {
           console.log('Scanned something', text);
            this.data = text;
           QRScanner.hide(); // hide camera preview
           scanSub.unsubscribe(); // stop scanning
           this.ionApp.style.display = 'block';
         });

       } else if (status.denied) {
         // camera permission was permanently denied
         // you must use QRScanner.openSettings() method to guide the user to the settings page
         // then they can grant the permission from there
       } else {
         // permission was denied, but not permanently. You can ask for permission again at a later time.
       }
    })
    .catch((e: any) =>this.error = e); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it dosn't directly solve your issue but if you are using Ionic 3+ I would recommend using @ionic-native/barcode-scanner https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner.
It supports both barcodes and QR codes and is really easy to implement.